# Real world monte-carlo (P-measure)

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, stochastic-discount

Consider the 2 following approaches to pricing a security:

**Monte-carlo ($\mathbb{Q}$-measure)**

$\begin{equation}
C = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{-rT} max(S_i(t) - K, 0)
\end{equation}$

**Monte-carlo ($\mathbb{P}$-measure)**

$\begin{equation}
C = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{n} D_i max(S_{i}(t) - K, 0)
\end{equation}$

where $D_i = \left(\frac{q_i}{p_i}\right) \frac{1}{(1+r)^t}$ is the stochastic discount factor / deflator / pricing kernel under scenario $i$.

Furthermore, I assume that

\begin{align}
ln(S_t/S_0) &\sim N(r - 0.5\sigma^2, \sigma\sqrt{T}) \mbox{ under the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure} \\
ln(S_t / S_0) &\sim N(\alpha - 0.5\sigma^2, \sigma\sqrt{T}) \mbox{ under the $\mathbb{P}$ measure}
\end{align}
I am wondering how to calculate $q_i$ and $p_i$. Then I would like to compare $C$ under the Black-Scholes, Monte-carlo $\mathbb{Q}$ measure and Monte-carlo $\mathbb{P}$ measure.

I expect that $C_{BS}(S=100, \ K=100, \ \sigma=0.25, \ r=0.03,\  T=1) = 11.35$ is close to $C_{MC, \mathbb{Q}} \ (N=10,000)$ and $C_{MC, \mathbb{P}} \ (N=10,000)$.

I use the standard Monte-Carlo technique - i.e. I simulate values of $S(1)$ by taking a random draw from a normal distribution and converting this to the appropriate lognormal distribution.

Comment: This post has helped me understand pricing under P measure. Thank you. Just one question: how/where do you get
`Di=(qi/pi) * 1/(1+r)^t`

Answer (score 3):

Essentially the question is importance sampling
$$
\int f(S_T) \psi_{r}(S_T) dS_T = \int f(S_T) \psi_{\alpha}(S_T)  \frac{\psi_r}{\psi_\alpha}(S_T) dS_T 
$$
Here $\psi_{\mu}$ denotes the log-normal density with drift $\mu.$ So when you simulate with drift $\alpha$ each sample used is 
$$
f(S_T)  \frac{\psi_r}{\psi_\alpha}(S_T)
$$
instead of $f(S_T).$

You can also do a change of variable and write the integral in terms of $\log S_T$ to get simpler expressions for the densities.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I think I figured it out.

Under the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure,

$\begin{equation}
S_t \sim LN(ln(S_0) + r - 0.5\sigma^2, \ \sigma\sqrt{t})
\end{equation}$

Under the $\mathbb{P}$ measure

$\begin{equation}
S_t \sim LN(ln(S_0) + \alpha - 0.5\sigma^2, \ \sigma\sqrt{t})
\end{equation}$

Suppose we simulate the following stock prices

```
Si = 96.33, 69.04, 115.19
```

The corresponding probabilities of observing these prices under the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure are

```
qi = 0.0164, 0.00777, 0.0118
```

The corresponding probabilities of observing these prices under the $\mathbb{P}$ measure are

```
pi = 0.01615, 0.006879, 0.01228
```

The stochastic discount factors are $\left( \frac{q_i}{p_i} \right) e^{-r}$

```
 Di = 0.9848683 1.0956499 0.9301017
```

We can then compute the Monte-carlo price of the option under the $\mathbb{P}$ measure using

$\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{3} max(0, S_i - K) D_i
\end{equation}$

Comment: 2 questions: how do you determine $\alpha$, and how do you define probability of observing $S_i$ under $\mathbb{Q}$ for a continuous distribution?

Comment: $\alpha$ can be estimated from the historical stock prices. Suppose we've observed $S_1, \dots, S_n$ and calculated $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$ where $x_i = ln(S_{i+1} / S_{i})$. Let $\mu$ represent the mean of the $x_i$ terms and $s^2$ represent the variance of the $x_i$ terms. Then $\alpha$ can be estimated by $\mu + 0.5 s^2$. For question 2, since we made the assumption that $S_t \sim LN( )$ under the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure, we have the probability density function, $P(S = S_t)$.

Comment: But for any continuous distribution, the probability of observing any specific value is 0.

Comment: There's no need to be condescending. For $X$ continuous, $Pr[a \le X \le b] = \int_a^b f(x) dx$. If $a=b$ then that probability is 0.

Comment: I'm sorry my last comment was little rude. I'll try to explain why the probability of observing any specific value is technically zero, but that isn't what a pdf describes exactly. Consider a continuous cumulative distribution function $F$. $F(-\infty)$ = 0 and $F(\infty) = 1$. Define $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$. Clearly $f(x)$ is not equal to 0 at all points. In fact $f(x)$ can be interpreted as the probability that $x$ lies within the area near $x$

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree. I didn't say that $f$ is 0. If you define $f(x)$ as you have, then $Pr[a \le X \le b] = F(b) - F(a)$, which is clearly 0 if $a = b$.

Comment: Consider this: suppose $Y$ is standard normal, with $g_Y(y)$ the pdf of $Y$. Then $g(0) = 0.3989...$. This does not mean that $Pr[Y=0] = 0.4$, not even close. In fact, for the probability to be 0.4, you would have $Pr[-0.52 < Y < 0.52]$.

Comment: Else suppose $Y$ is $N(0, 0.1)$, then $f(0) = 1.26... >> 1$